# Get full path of file in node.js with module express-busboy

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, busboy

I am using node.js and express-busboy to upload a file from a file input form to the server. The uploaded file will have a path of something like `root/useruploaded/formattached/somerandomid(e.g. 9w470066-68b4-549e-9607-1987c72768ac)/myFileInputName/uploaded.file`

My express-busboy settings look like this:

```
bb.extend(app, {
  upload: true,
  path: path.join(__dirname, '/useruploaded/formattached'),
  allowedPath: /^\/contact$/ // <-- My POST
});
```

Then when I access the file by doing `req.files.contactFileUpload.filename` I can successfully get the name of the uploaded file.

However, when I go to attach this file to my email, I need the path, which I can't figure out how to get because of the random id folder that busboy puts the user uploaded content into. Otherwise I would be able to do something like

```
path = path.join(__dirname, '/useruploaded/formattached', req.files.contactFileUpload.filename);
```

To get the path.

My question is how can I

Stop busboy from putting my files in a random id folder?

**OR**

Get the full path of the file?

I have tried to do `req.files.contactFileUpload.path`, but this returns undefined.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to get the property `file` on your object ? https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy/blob/e49e3b48f3e4c005c017589b9111ef2ab6b60d65/index.js#L123 like this `req.files.contactFileUpload.file`

Comment: @Zagonine If I understand what you're saying - req.files.contactFileUpload.file.path also returns undefined

Comment: No just do : `req.files.contactFileUpload.file`

Comment: @Zagonine Thanks, that worked. If you would like to post that as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks! JFYI: I don't know if you know the module `multer`, but I think it is better than `express-busboy` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the uploaded file path at the property `file` of the returned object.

In your case, in order to get the filepath, you have to do :

```
req.files.contactFileUpload.file
```